# How to fix FQDN Mismatch for intel AMT system with Intel SCS 10

Tags: intel

I have two systems on my domain and have configured Intel AMT with SCS. However I had need to change the Host Name on both systems and afterwards the SCS database is not getting updated correctly after a maintenance Task. The DB still shows old FQDN's and discovery is saying there is a mismatch error. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source used to configure the FQDN setting (hostname.suffix) in the Intel AMT device is defined in the configuration profile. The profile includes several options that you can use to define how the FQDN of the device will be constructed.
When changes are made to the host computer or the network environment, the basis on which the FQDN setting was constructed might change. These changes can include changing the hard disk, replacing the operating system, or re-assigning the computer to a different user. If the FQDN setting in the Intel AMT device
is not updated with these changes, problems can occur.

Intel SCS includes options that you can use to detect and fix these “mismatches”.

Intel AMT configuration is bounded to your platforms HW, since the records on the SCS DB are currently in a mismatch status due with the information in your AMT host in order to remedy the situation you will require to perform the following procedures in order to fix the mismatch:

1. Download ACUConfig.exe to your AMT host and run the following command: 
    `ACUConfig.exe SystemDiscovery /ReportToRCS /AdminPassword <password> RCSAddress <RCSAddress>`  in your AMT host platform, where the values in pointy brackets need to be replaced with the values for your environment.
2. Under the **Monitoring > Views** tab you will see the system that was detected to have a missmatch, in order to reconcile the records in the DB you will need to perform one more action.
3. Create a Job. In the Job Definition window, select these options:

   - From the drop-down list in the Filter section, select Host FQDN Mismatch.
   - From the Operation drop-down list, select Fix host FQDN mismatch.

Now all that is left to do is run the job using the context menu on the recently created job. You can monitor the log of the AMT host log for more details and also you will see that the record in the Mismatch View gets cleared.

Good Luck!